# Redirecting & masking only one specific subdomain with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following `.htaccess` that is working perfectly for me. Now, I'm trying to mask just 1 subdomain with its folder. I've got everything set-up on the DNS end and right now when I type in `app.domain.com` it resolves to `www.domain.com/app`.

I need it to stay `app.domain.com` in the URL bar however, not just redirect to the folder.

I've been at this for 2 hours and can't figure it out. Anyone know what I should do?

Here's my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^app.example.com

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the issue correctly, a user goes to `http://app.example.com`, you'd like that user to be redirected to `http://app.example.com/app`. Is that right? If that is the case, then simply add an alias on your virtual host so that `example.com` and `app.example.com` are both valid hostnames for that directory.

Find your **httpd-vhosts.conf** file or equivalent and configure your virtual host with something to the effect of the following example:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/site/folder
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias app.example.com example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is [more information on the ServerAlias directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias) if you want to research it further.